# Fail to update database through jtextfield

Tags: java, sql

I want to update several values to database using jtextfield, but when I click save jbutton somehow only my jtable is updated, my database not updated at all.

I've tried looking for answer through google and youtube, none of it answer my problem.
I've checked my query in phpmyadmin and it's work.

Here is the code for jbutton that update the database :

```
   private void btn_simpan_tabelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              
        String akta = txt_no_akta_tabel.getText();
        String nm_suami= txt_nm_suami_tabel.getText();
        String al_suami = txt_alamat_suami_tabel.getText();
        String nm_istri= txt_nm_istri_tabel.getText();
        String al_istri= txt_alamat_istri_tabel.getText();
        String nm_wali= txt_nama_wali_tabel.getText();
        Date tg_nikah= txt_tanggal_nikah_tabel.getDate();

         try
            {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection kon = DriverManager.getConnection(database,
                                                user,
                                                pass);
                Statement stt = kon.createStatement();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String tgl = sdf.format(txt_tanggal_nikah_tabel.getDate());
                String SQL = "UPDATE `tabel_nikah` "
                        + "SET `no_akta` = '"+akta+"', "
                        + "`nama_suami` = '"+nm_suami+"', "
                        + "`alamat_suami` = '"+al_suami+"', "
                        + "`nama_istri` = '"+nm_istri+"', "
                        + "`alamat_istri` = '"+al_istri+"', "
                        + "`nama_wali` = '"+nm_wali+"', "
                        + "`tanggal_nikah` = '"+tgl+"' "
                        + "WHERE "
                        + "`primary_key` = '"+tableModel.getValueAt(row, 
                          0).toString()+"'";
                stt.executeUpdate(SQL);

                SimpleDateFormat dmy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

                data[1]=akta;
                data[2]=nm_suami;
                data[3]=al_suami;
                data[4]=nm_istri;
                data[5]=al_istri;
                data[6]=nm_wali;
                data[7]=dmy.format(txt_tanggal_nikah_tabel.getDate());
                tableModel.removeRow(row);
                tableModel.insertRow(row, data);
                stt.close();
                kon.close();
          catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
            {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

There is no error messages at all.
I'm really confused to solve this problem.

Comment: 1. Please check the return value of executeUpdate(...). 2. What is the value of `tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0)` ? 3. Check whether there is a row with this primary key in table `tabel_nikah`.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh I've checked the ```tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0)``` using ```System.out.println(tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();```
it does have value of the ```primary_key```
by the way the row here is from ```int row = 0; 
row = tabel_nikah.getSelectedRow();```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what is the return value of executeUpdate(...) ?

Comment: @AedvaldTseh you mean return value when I checked it with ```System.out.println(tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();```? it says 2 because I clicked the 2nd row of jtable

Comment: Change `stt.executeUpdate(SQL);` to `int i=stt.executeUpdate(SQL);` and add `System.out.println(i)`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **NOT** concatenate user input into a SQL string like that. Learn how to correctly use a `PreparedStatement`. And pass `date` values as instances of `java.time.LocalDate` or at least `java.sql.Date`, _never_ as a String

Comment: @AedvaldTseh ah my bad, it took so long its says 0.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't really get what you say about pass ```date``` thing, sorry I'm still really new at java..

Comment: @AedvaldTseh when I execute your query, there's no result.
also I cant find any button to upvote your comment.
my reputation still 6. sorry.